# FCM push message sending without topic and different data block

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible that I send a push message without topic subscribing and different data block?

I tried "registration_ids" or "to" parameter

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hi Developer. Your post is quite unclear. Can you put more details?